# Можно ли сделать swipable recyclerview не используя сторонние библиотеки?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Нужно сделать recyclerview как на картинке, чтоб при свайпе появлялись кнопки, для этого надо использовать что-то типо [этого](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) или я что-то не так понимаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Можно и самому](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/custom-swipe-recyclerview.html).

Comment: А как? Что прочитать не подскажите ?

Comment: И как лучше это реализовать, используя сторонние либы или самому?

Comment: Моя фраза «Можно и самому» в первом комментарии кликабельна, там можете почитать. А по поводу самому или нет – выбор за Вами. Скорее всего придется самому.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил)